# using i18n.DataAnnotations . How exactly does it work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, localization, internationalization

I am implementing a multilingual site with asp.net mvc 3.
A friend suggested me this project https://github.com/danielcrenna/i18n

Until now i have succeded to make it work in controllers and views (razor) but not in data annotation.

For example

```
public class LogOnModel
{
    [i18n.DataAnnotations.Email]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Field")]
    [i18n.DataAnnotations.DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [i18n.DataAnnotations.Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Field")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [i18n.DataAnnotations.Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [i18n.DataAnnotations.Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

The above piece of code should produce new entries in .po files , whenever the build is successful. But nothing happens whatsoever.

Is there anybody that has knowledge of this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same problem with Daniel Crenna i18n project. Have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the i18n framework you're using from GitHub, but if it helps, there is something similar in .NET. The way you do this in .NET isn't based on .po but on resources compiled into satellite assemblies.

For MVC you can use the [DisplayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.aspx) to specify the type which contains the resource string you wish to use. There are equivalent attributes for validation messages.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that with i18n v1 is not possible to make working i18n.DataAnnotations, I asked as issue at github https://github.com/turquoiseowl/i18n/issues/104